# Can someone please convert the below code using the 'Select' extension method?

Tags: select

Can someone please convert the below code using the 'Select' extension      method?

```
 //  
 int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 }; 
 string[] strings = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
 var textNums = 
 from n in numbers 
     select strings[n];
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code coversion service.

Comment: You should fix the formatting and add the c# tag

Answer (score -1):

```
var textNums = numbers.Select(n => strings[n]);
```